# How to renew Lets encrypt certificate in ejabberd configured server?

Tags: ejabberd, debian-jessie

How to renew Lets encrypt certificate in ejabberd configured server? My server is Debian-jessie and I have tried to renew SSL certificates using the below command,
certbot certonly -d mydomainname

But it produced an unexpected error:

> Failed authorization procedure. : urn:acme:error:connection ::Timeout
>   during connect (likely firewall problem). Skipping.

Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.

Comment: I may be wrong but you need a http server for letsencrypt to work.

Comment: If you are using certbot, this is not an ejabberd specific error. As the error message says, the issue can be a wrong DNS setup, or firewall issues. The exact cause depend on the validation method used in your case.

Comment: Thanks emix and Mickeal for the valued comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the proper answer for this:

> You need to stop the service ejabberd service before you do the
>   process,

```
 service ejabberd stop
```

> Then move the expired ssl pem file to somewhere else,

```
mv /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem  /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem.backup
```

> Go to the directory where the cert boot locating,

```
cd /root
```

> Enter the below command in-order to renew the certificate for the
>    required domain

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /etc/ejabberd -d yourdomain.com --force-renewal --rsa-key-size 4096
```

Then merge the generated ssl files to the ejabberd configuration file

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem > ejabberd.pem
```

> Then move the pem file to the ejabberd root path

```
mv ejabberd.pem /etc/ejabberd

chown ejabberd /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem
```

> Enable ejabberd service

```
service ejabberd start

service ejabberd status
```